# update is not a function firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Using the three-way data binding of Firebase and loving it. Something weird happening though:

I have this:

```
  var fire = $firebaseObject(DatabaseRef.child('fire').child($stateParams.fireId));

  fire.$bindTo($scope, "formData")
  .then(function() {
    fire.update($scope.formData)
      .then(function(data) {
        toastr.info('Updating ongoing', 'Busy');
      }, function(error) {
        toastr.error(error.message, error.reason);
      })
  })
```

Although the three-way data binding works, changes reflect in controller, templates and firebase database remote, I get the error:

```
angular.js:13920 TypeError: fire.update is not a function
```

I'm doing something wrong somewhere, just don't know where. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: `$firebaseObject` doesn't have a method called `update()`: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks